# Depth of convolution layers in DNN

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I was reading this morning the paper on the architecture of Alexnet and there is one thing I cannot understand. On the convolution first layer, after the ReLu activation and the response normalisation across kernels to induce competition the second convolution layer input has the size 55x55x48. My doubt is on the depth of this layer, what logic drives them to structure the output of the first convolution in that manner?

Here is a picture of the network for illustration:

[image]

Is this linked to the size of the features you expect to find on the image?

Thanks a lot and hope the question is clear